# Bootstrap artcile style

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I often wonder if it's possible to build a responsive article with Bootstrap WITHOUT dividing content.

For example at the beginning it seems pretty simple : 
[image]

Basically it would be a row with 4 columns (let's say col-lg-3).

You would have to divide your text in 4 parts. Legit ... But i can't ask my users to divide their text.

Is there a good library out here to do that ?

I tried to write an angular module but i'm not happy with the result because I count how many words I have and I divide it by 4, 3, 2, 1 based on screen size.

The problem is that some words are longer than others and i end up with columns longer than others. If you have any idea i would be glad to hear !

EDIT : I made an angular directive to build responsive articles in a mater of seconds : [Github](https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-multiple-columns), [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XionakrnmSpRJ7MN0aFj?p=preview)

`<multiple-columns
      col-xs="1"
      col-sm="2"
      col-md="3"
      col-lg="4"
      justify="true"
      text="Lorem ipsum ...">
      </multiple-columns>`

Comment: i don't know such a library (but it surely exists) - but why don't you count the characters instead of counting the words and divide the strings at the nearest space?

Comment: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done quite easily through CSS - no plugin required! Although, it is not supported in IE 9.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Also make sure to check out the example: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count

Comment: Seems really awesome ! I've been looking for something like that for so long, but i was looking for javascript plugins mostly. I didn't think it was possible with only css, thanks ! (i wait a bit more but your answer is probably going to be accepted)

Comment: I tried to reduce the browser size but it does not seem to change column number. It's 3 at the beginning but i would like to have only 2 and 1, is that possible ?

Comment: Arf, even if it's not directly possible to change the number of columns in css i can manage to make it with javascript ! I'll update this post if i take the time to make a js module :) !

Comment: @Maxime Remember that you can use media queries to change `column-count` as browser size changes, which should give you what you're asking for.

Comment: You're right, i think i was tired and should have think about that before asking ;) Thanks

Comment: @Maxime sorry, I didn't realize you had questions! Yes - media queries are the solution to your problem. See: https://scotch.io/quick-tips/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries for exact media queries to use